# Azure Databricks: can't connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have Storage account `kagsa1` with container `cont1` inside and need it to accessible (mounted) via Databricks

If I use storage account key in KeyVault it works correctly:

```
configs = {
    "fs.azure.account.key.kagsa1.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "kv-db1", key = "storage-account-access-key")
}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://cont1@kagsa1.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/cont1",
  extra_configs = configs)

dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/cont1")
```

..but if I'm trying to connect using Azure Active Directory credentials:

```
configs = {
"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "CustomAccessToken",
"fs.azure.account.custom.token.provider.class": spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.passthrough.adls.gen2.tokenProviderClassName")
}

dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://cont1@kagsa1.dfs.core.windows.net/")
```

..it fails:

```
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils.ls.
: GET https://kagsa1.dfs.core.windows.net/cont1?resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&timeout=90&recursive=false
StatusCode=403
StatusDescription=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
ErrorCode=AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
ErrorMessage=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

Databrics Workspace tier is Premium,
Cluster has Azure Data Lake Storage Credential Passthrough option enabled,
Storage account has hierarchical namespace option enabled,
Filesystem was initialized with

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "true")
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://cont1@kagsa1.dfs.core.windows.net/")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "false")
```

and I have full access to container in storage account:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** When performing the steps in the Assign the application to a role, make sure to assign the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to the service principal.

As part of repro, I have provided **owner** permission to the service principal and tried to run the “**dbutils.fs.ls("mnt/azure/")**”, returned same error message as above.

[image]

Now assigned the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to the service principal.

[image]

Finally, able to get the output without any error message after assigning Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal.

[image]

For more details, refer “[Tutorial: Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure Databricks & Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark)”.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - ADLS Gen2 throws 403 error message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c8d58a4-04d1-4d0a-a9fa-c48c9991f1ab/azure-databricks-throwing-403-error?forum=AzureDatabricks).